# special character data in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a special unicode character like smileys in a column, but i am not able to find out how many rows has such type of data?

Comment: "how many rows" typically requires `count()`

Comment: Identifying an emoticon is the real difficult "thing" here. There is no "Like Emoticon character" syntax, and it's not like the characters are between a certain range of character positions. Also what the character looks like depends on the font. This character (`NCHAR(9999)`), ✏, [looks like an emoticon in my IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoE7a.png) but doesn't here in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -

```
CREATE TABLE #Tmp_test(col NVARCHAR(1000));

INSERT INTO #Tmp_test(col) VALUES (N'My data has ')
,(N'My data has ')
,(N'My data has ')
,(N'No emoji');

SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM #Tmp_test WHERE CAST(col AS varchar(100)) != col;
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO #Tmp_test(col) VALUES (N'Ɨ'); SELECT col FROM #Tmp_test WHERE CAST(col AS varchar(100)) != col;` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=73175d9eb559efa453ffd073bad76c37)

Comment: Or, alternatively, as you `CAST` to a `varchar(100)` but the column is defined as a `nvarchar(1000)`: `INSERT INTO #Tmp_test(col) VALUES (REPLICATE('A', 101)); SELECT col FROM #Tmp_test WHERE CAST(col AS varchar(100)) != col;` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0446285175917bb540b23af4b6e08d22)